# How to check multiple condition for same field in my SQL?

Tags: mysql, select-query

Following table:

```
ECNO    BRANCH   MONTH  ISDELETED
1   B1  February 2018   n
2   B3  February 2018   n
3   B3  March    2018   n
4   B1  March    2018   n
5   B2  January  2018   n
6   B3  January  2018   n
```

Here we need to select according to branch and starting date and end date.

Case1:
If branch is B3, starting date and end date is equal then
pick according the branch selected.

```
select * from HR_BULKBILL_DETAILS where BRANCH='B3' AND MONTH='March 2018'
```

This query works fine

Case 2:
If Staring date (Assume January 2018) and End date (Assume Febuary 2018) And Branch b3. How to check this condition in select query

How Check two condition for one field?

Note: (In database we have only column Month:this hold month- year example : Januray 2018)
I am using my sql.

We have tried:

```
select * from HR_BULKBILL_DETAILS where  MONTH='February 2018' AND MONTH='March 2018' AND BRANCH='CBE3'
```

Forgive me if any typo.

My Expected Output is:

ECNO    BRANCH  MONTH   ISDELETED
2   B3  February 2018   n
3   B3  March 2018  n

My Input is user give startedate and end date  and brach

Startdate and enddate will be like March 2018

Comment: not quite understand what you mean.. you can try changing "AND" to "OR" or "BETWEEN"

Comment: You need to show us the expected output here.  Your second query obviously will never return any records, because the month can only have one value.

Comment: Month is like date field.

Comment: Sorry wait I will share expected ouput.

Comment: 2   B3  February 2018   n
3   B3  March 2018  n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rows for Feb or March, then say that:

```
select  *
    from  HR_BULKBILL_DETAILS
    where  ( MONTH='February 2018' OR  MONTH='March 2018' )
      AND  BRANCH='CBE3'
```

Be sure to use parentheses, else the precedence of `AND` and `OR` will mess up the query.

If you need *between* Feb and June, then you cannot do that easily.  You would be better off storing a `"2018-02-01" in a`DATE` column so that you can do comparisons such as

```
WHERE month BETWEEN "2018-02-01" AND "2018-06-01"
```

You can then use a date function (see the manual) to turn "2018-02-01" into "February 2018" in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks AKZhang,
Finally I got result by using "between"

Following is the query:

select * from HR_BULKBILL_DETAILS where MONTH Between 'February 2018' AND 'March 2018' and BRANCH='B3'

Comment: Looking at the months as strings, guess what?  "January 2018" is between those two month!  So are June and July.  F < J < M